# how do you add the live.map function from covid19.analytics to a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, maps, plotly, interactive

Im trying to create a covid19 interactive information application and I'm having a lot of trouble adding my live.map() from the covid19.analytics package to my application

```
   library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)
    library(covid19.analytics)
    library(plotly)

    ui <- fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("cosmo"), 
            navbarPage( "COVID 19 APPLICATION",
              tabPanel(
                "Interactive COVID 19 MAP",
                  sidebarPanel(
                      
                    ),
                       mainPanel(
                  plotlyOutput("map")
                  )
                ), tabPanel(
                  "Countries",
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput(inputId = "countries", label = "country selection", choices = c("country 1", "country 2", "country 3")), 
                      
                    ),
                 mainPanel(
                    plotOutput( outputId = "countries") 
                  )     
                  ),
                
                 tabPanel(
                  "coolness XD",
                  sidebarPanel( ),
                    
                mainPanel(
                    plotOutput( outputId = "coolness") 
                  )  
                 
                )
            
                ),
              ) 

    server <- function(input,output){
  

    output$map <- renderPlotly({
    x <- live.map()
    output$map <- x
  })
 
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)


output$map <- renderPlotly({
    x <- live.map()
    output$map <- x
  })
 
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I am still a beginner in shiny so its a bit confusing working with the renderplot/renderplotly functions. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, I still get the error. Unexpected plotly output for mapUnexpected htmlwidget output for map how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of things that have to be fixed:

1. in the live.map fn you need to set the argument `interactive.display=FALSE` otherwise `live.map` will launch its own web rendering
2. your server section needs to be modified as follow,

```
    server <- function(input,output){
                output$map <- renderPlotly({
                x <- live.map(interactive.display=FALSE)
              })
    }
```

ie. you don't need to reassign x to output$map from within renderPlotly

Take a look also at some of the examples from the covid19.analytics dashboard explorer, https://github.com/mponce0/covid19.analytics/blob/master/R/covid19_dashboard.R

3. Finally the last "orphan" `output$map <- ...` outside the server fn definition should be removed and only once instance of `shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)` is needed.